# Is it possible to sign a message using the private key of a contract account?

Tags: contracts, key, signing

For example, I have deployed an `ink!` contract via polkadot apps.

Is it possible to obtain the private key of the contract account and sign an arbitrary message?

Comment: I think contract accounts are randomly generated by the chain and therefore have no known private keys.

Comment: Added my comment to a follow up [question](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7303/is-it-possible-to-prove-that-an-account-deployed-contract-a-from-within-contract)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible to obtain the private key of a contract account.