# Is it possible to prove that an account deployed contract A from within contract B without the account being stored in contract A?

Tags: ink, contracts, proof-system

`Account A` deploys `Contract A`. `Account A` then calls `Contract B` function `register`, passing the address of `Contract A`. Is it possible to prove that `Account A` deployed `Contract A` from within the register function of `Contract B` without implementing some kind of proof of deployment function in `Contract A`?

### Contract A

Deployed by `Account A`. The contract contains no record of `Account A` in storage.

### Contract B

`Account A` then calls this function passing the `Contract A` address.

```
pub fn register(
    &mut self,
    dapp_account: AccountId,
) -> Result<(), Error> {
    let caller = self.env().caller();

    // check that the dapp_account is a contract
    if !self.env().is_contract(&dapp_account) {
         return Err(Error::InvalidContract);
    }

    // prove that the caller deployed `dapp_account`
    // ?? check the contracts.instantiateWithCode extrinsic plus a merkle trie proof of the block inclusion on-chain?
```

I'm assuming this would require the contract instantiate extrinsic, a proof of the extrinsic being in a block, and a proof of the block being on-chain.

Answer (score 1):

In the contract_pallet there is a mapping between the code hash and the owner of the contract. (see the [code](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/contracts/src/lib.rs#L911)).

```
#[pallet::storage]
pub(crate) type OwnerInfoOf<T: Config> = StorageMap<_, Identity, CodeHash<T>, OwnerInfo<T>>;
```

But I see that what you have is not the hash, is the account ID of the contract, then you will have to query first the [ContractInfoOf](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/contracts/src/lib.rs#L942) which is a mapping between the contract accountId and the contract info (which includes [the code hash](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/contracts/src/storage.rs#L55))

```
#[pallet::storage]
pub(crate) type ContractInfoOf<T: Config> =
    StorageMap<_, Twox64Concat, T::AccountId, ContractInfo<T>>;
```

Is possible to interact with the runtime from a ink! smart contract with  [chain extensions](https://use.ink/macros-attributes/chain-extension/), see this previous StackExchange answers that has some examples of how to achieve that:

- https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/1954/2762
- https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/3949/2762

Comment: Thanks. `ink!` [can provide the `code_hash` of a contract at an `AccountId`](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/7cf12afc65781aa8a3c473b876a04c30aaa4afc5/crates/env/src/api.rs#L561-L574) without chain extensions. I'm looking to prove contract deployment by an account without the use of chain extensions, which are not guaranteed to exist.